# PrimeFaces OverlayPanel causes JavaScript error "TypeError: f is undefined"

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I was trying to use the `<p:overlayPanel>` as a widget as described in PrimeFaces showcase example (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/overlayPanel.xhtml).

I built a simple app, but on page load it directly causes the JavaScript error `TypeError: f is undefined` at column 3, row 1457 in "/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.1"

The xhtml body code is:

```
<h:form id="form"> 

    <p:commandButton update=":form:infoPanel" oncomplete="PF('testOverlayPanel').show('#{component.clientId}')" value="Test"/>

    <p:overlayPanel widgetVar="testOverlayPanel" dismissable="false" showCloseIcon="true">
        <p:outputPanel id="infoPanel" style="text-align:center;">
            Hello OverlayPanel!
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:overlayPanel>

</h:form>
```

When I removed the overlayPanel, the JavaScript error disappears.

When I press the command button, two further JavaScript errors appear:

1. NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - https://localhost:8443/test/index.xhtml
2. TypeError: PF(...) is undefined

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1 with JSF 2.2.8

Comment: Do you have h:head, h:body etc?

Comment: @Jaqen: likely, otherwise `primefaces.js` wouldn't be loaded in first place.

Comment: Yep thought too but who knows :-)

Comment: Correct. It's strange: when I add `id="cmdBtnId"` to the command button and a `for="cmdBtnId"` to the overlayPanel it works fine. But I don't want to bind the overlayPanel to one button, it should be bind to a list of buttons, as in the showcase example from PrimeFaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using it like in the showcase ;-). The

```
<p:commandButton update=":form:infoPanel" 
    oncomplete="PF('testOverlayPanel').show('#{component.clientId}')"
    value="Test"/>
```

is for the use in a datatable (as can be seen in the showcase). Normally you just need to do a

```
<p:commandButton update=":form:infoPanel" 
    oncomplete="PF('testOverlayPanel').show()" value="Test"/>
```

But if the overlayPanel is 'bound' to a specific button, you can also add the 'for' attribute on the overlayPanel if you put an id on the button like

```
<p:commandButton id="imageBtn" value="Basic" type="button" />
<p:overlayPanel id="imagePanel" for="imageBtn" hideEffect="fade">
    <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/nature/nature1.jpg" width="300" />
</p:overlayPanel>
```

(not sure how the latter goes with ajax calls)

Comment: Yes, the goal is to use it within a datalist, I tried that too, but failed. Are you sure that it's just for a datatable?

Comment: It is at least for a datatable and not for how you used it above.   If it also works for a datalist, I don't know.  Never tried and no time to try the coming days

Comment: It seems that datalist works with `<p:dialog>` only. Thanks for your hints!

Comment: @philsner, you marked this issue resolved, but did it really work inside datatable? I am having same issue PF('overlayWidgetVar') undefined. (I used alert() to popup oncomplete to verify)

Comment: @BamaiWu: Yes it works in the datatable!  See the PrimeFaces showcase.  And your error is different

Comment: @Kukeltje, thanks for the reply. I did look the demo before I asked the question.  The source code in the showcase is not exactly the working code for the page (e.g. it is refering to #dtSelectionView, which is not shown in the code). Also I am not quite understanding this: PF('carOP').show('#{component.clientId}').  clientId in the show method, what does it do?

Comment: Please create your own question

Answer (score 1):

> I am using PrimeFaces 5.1 with JSF 2.2.8

On Primefaces version 5.1, if you let the p:overlay without the **for="imageBtn"** attribute, an error is show on browser console:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined*

The fix (actually an overlay refactor) has been commited on november 14, 2014, as you can see below:

https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/detail?r=12016

OverlayPanel won't work on Primefaces version 5.1 unless you specify the **"for"** attribute, and that is not the way it is specified to work with datatables.

Probably will work on version 5.1.3 and afterwards. See https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7615

Answer (score 0):

I think that @LeonardoHAlmeida posted the correct answer.
I found a workaround to avoid this bug. I just created a "fake" button just to be able to set a target for the "for" attribute in overlayPanel

```
<p:commandButton id="fakeButton" style="display: none"></p:commandButton>
```

So my overlay looks like:

```
<p:overlayPanel widgetVar="wOverlay" appendToBody="true"  for="fakeButton">
    <p:outputPanel id="display">
        ...
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:overlayPanel>
```

And the button in my datatable is:

```
<p:commandButton update=":form:display" oncomplete="PF('wOverlay').show('#{component.clientId}')" icon="ui-icon-search">
```